# How do I find air vents that are covered over with popcorn ceiling?

Tags: hvac

My house has several areas where we are have no heat vents and these areas are quite cold. Others areas have vents  even in the closet spaces. I found one covered vent after walking through my neighbors house, and know that there are others, but need a way to locate them. Any advise? Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but note that a lot of older popcorn ceilings [contain asbestos](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31821/popcorn-ceiling-in-old-building-but-ceiling-looks-new-asbestos-worries). It's generally harmless if not disturbed, but if you're not sure, use appropriate caution if you cut through it to expose vents.

Comment: Thanks, no asbestos, the house is 10 years old, but the contractor did a poor job and has since left the area. Dr. Meg

Comment: Ahh, I figured that if the vents were walled over (well ceilinged over) it must be an old house -- am surprised that's the case on such a new house!

Comment: Yes, a let down from our municipality. I am sure no one inspected this house before it was put on the market. Thanks

Comment: Do you have attic access?

Answer (score 3):

If the vent pipes are made of iron based metal or any covered over grate is made of similar material you could go hunting with a magnet.

Comment: Use a larger strong neodymium magnet, regular ones are not strong enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the ventilation system on max (hot or cold, either way) then use a handheld laser thermometer to look for temperature extremes.